# SVG box size larger than it should be

Tags: html, css, vue.js, svg, font-awesome

Why is svg box size so much bigger than path and g? No margins or padding, height or width. Tried to manipulate viewBox but it only messed things further. Any ideas?

Right now the bed is overlapping the circle so that hover on the circle does not apply. Only bed is affected (z-index).

[image: SVG Box size]

Font awesome + VUE:

```
<font-awesome-layers class="mb-4 fa-6x">
    <router-link to="/accommodation">
        <font-awesome-icon icon="circle" />
        <font-awesome-icon icon="circle" />
        <font-awesome-icon
            icon="bed"
            transform="shrink-8, left-2"
        />
    </router-link>
</font-awesome-layers>
```

Comment: maybe ask the Font Awesome team. They created the icons

Answer (score 0):

It could be mistake on their side, but I highly doubt someone as Font awesome would make mistake like that. Could you reproduce it in some snippet so I could try to figure that out?

Otherwise **if you could fit the icon fine and you only worry about hover effect** - I suggest to add this to svg and add hover effect on the circle.

```
svg { pointer-events: none; }
```

Comment: I thought about this. It has got something to do with the aligning of the layered images. There is no other way that these two images could be centered like they are without any other elements (container) doing the alignment. So basically there is no way for you to use hover effects on underlying image. Hover works only for the top most image.

Anyway this is not a problem anymore. I have to assign a JS method on mouseover and mouseout which acts as style changer.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to do with that hover effect, but you could do something like this in css `.circle:hover .svg:first-of-type { /* Styles applied to first svg on circle hover */ }`, or if you really need the hover effect on icon because it has different width/height, you could use some absolute positioned container with same width/height for that (or if you can't even create container or edit html, maybe you can create one using ::after on svg). There are many ways and in 99% of cases there's no need to use js. But if you used js and you are fine with that I guess it's ok.

Comment: You can't have hover effects on overlapping elements. Hover applies to the topmost element only. JS is the only way to make it happen.

Comment: Of course you can't. I didn't say that anywhere. JS definitely isn't the only way. I made a snippet for you with 2 CSS ways how to do that [link](https://jsfiddle.net/8upkrzs4/). By the way I wouldn't recommend using svg for circle icon. It's better to create it using div and give it border-radius 50%. You can then easily center the icon inside and with some styling you can be sure that the icon won't overflow your circle or get bigger than that.

Comment: Told you there's almost always a way(s) haha. You're welcome!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-rain-8oo2b?file=/src/App.vue

Here is a fiddle for you if you want to play with that one.

Answer (score 0):

So its like this:

```
<font-awesome-layers class="mb-4 fa-6x">
    <router-link to="/accommodation" id="fa-bed">
        <font-awesome-icon icon="circle" />
        <font-awesome-icon
            icon="bed"
            transform="shrink-8, left-2"
            @mouseover="faHoverStyle('fa-bed')"
            @mouseout="faNormalStyle('fa-bed')"
        />
    </router-link>
</font-awesome-layers>
```

---

```
methods: {
    faHoverStyle(e) {
        e = document.getElementById(e);
        e.getElementsByClassName("fa-circle")[0].classList.add(
            "fa-circle-hover"
        );
    },
    faNormalStyle(e) {
        e = document.getElementById(e);
        e.getElementsByClassName("fa-circle")[0].classList.remove(
            "fa-circle-hover"
        );
    }
}
```

---

```
.fa-circle {
    color: $color3;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.fa-circle-hover {
    color: $color1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Now you have hover on both images.

[image]